# Json parsing using Jackson Parser in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am a newbie in Android , I am doing a project where json parsing is done by calling a URL. I am able to do this by using built-in json parser provided by android.
But when i try to parse  huge json response ,it fails. I got to know about another parser, "Jackson parser". 
I googled a lot,but with no luck.
So , can anybody suggest me a way to parse json using Jackson parser through url?

```
          OR
```

Provide me some example links, if possible?
I think, It will be helpful to other newbies like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using thed Gson lib to deserialize json objects. Less painful to use, and it supports large objects quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give the package [org.json](http://d.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) a try. It is provided directly from the Android sdk.
[JSONObjects](http://d.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) can directly be parsed and provided to your objects i.g. via the constructor.

Comment: thanks, u r talking about built-in android, i successfully completed this project, i stucked at one point, when i try to parse json response of more than 3 MB

Comment: What exactly fails, when parsing that? Is there a relevant stack trace?

Comment: i am getting outofmemory exception while trying to parse huge amount of data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115494/outofmemoryexception-when-parsing-large-json-responses

Comment: So there already is an answer that looks good to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115494/outofmemoryexception-when-parsing-large-json-responses/6115522#6115522

Comment: @hussain : if your getting out of memory exception because every application have limited memory.So, you have to divide your json response in your web service. please see web service documentation of facebook or twitter these will help you.

Comment: my question is, Is there any example link for jackson parser in android? Any kind of help will be highly appreciable(thanks in advance)

Comment: You will still get out OutOfMemoryExceptions when trying to parse the data with Jackson. The Jackson parser is very unlikely to solve this problem.

Comment: But have you had a look at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JACKSON/Tutorial?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true yet?

Comment: well, can u give some implementation way, how to bind data from url to ObjectMapper ?

Comment: How to call url , get inputstream into ObjectMapper for further processing?

Comment: well, i feel that example was given for filesystem operation, i need to get json response by calling URL ?I did not find any idea there regarding that?